# Given recursive formula $a_n = 2a_{n-1}+1$, show $a_n = 2^n -1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion, analysis-of-algorithms

I came across a recursion homework problem for a graduate algorithms class while looking at recursive algorithms.

We are given a recursive formula for a recursive algorithm that gives the total number of moves at the $n^{\text{th}}$ recursion based on the $(n-1)^{\text{st}}$ recursion:
$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 1,
$$
where $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 3$.

How do we show that the final explicit formula is $a_n = 2^n - 1$?

Comment: Given function $f(x)=2x+1$, $$a(n)=\underbrace{f\circ f \circ\ldots\circ f}_{\text{$n$ times}}(0)$$ Hint: Think in binary. Applying $f$ is same as appending a $1$ to the end of the number.

Comment: **Hint** : define $b(n) = a(n) -1$

Comment: $a_2=3$ doesn't need to be stipulated, because $a_2=2a_1+1=2\cdot1+1=3$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by Induction for a recursive sequence and a formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536404/proof-by-induction-for-a-recursive-sequence-and-a-formula)

Comment: @Gonçalo the question is very similar but the post is asking for induction as a solution specifically and the formula is not included in the title. My question also accepts solutions not only based on induction and is shorter in length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could show $a_n=2^n-1$ by [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).  Base case:  $a_1=1=2^1-1.$

Now assume $a_n=2^n-1.$  Then $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1=2(2^n-1)+1=2^{n+1}-2+1=2^{n+1}-1$.

QED

Comment: very nice and quick solution! I will upvote it because it is the shortest of the rest.

Answer (score 3):

My approach was somewhat different from the three approaches above. Even though the question has been thoroughly answered, I'd like to share it anyway.

Consider that if $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 1$, then $a_{n-1} = 2a_{n-2} + 1$.

It can be concluded that $a_n - a_{n-1} = 2(a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})$ since:

\begin{aligned}
a_n - a_{n-1} &= (2a_{n-1} + 1) - (2a_{n-2} + 1) \\
&= 2a_{n-1} + 1 - 2a_{n-2} -1 \\
&= 2a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2} \\
&= 2(a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})
\end{aligned}

This represents a property of exponential functions; each successive difference is double the last. Therefore, the relationship should be akin to an exponential with a base of $2$.

Let $f(n) = 2^{n} - k$. The above property of the recursive relationship can be demonstrated by determining the difference between $f(n)$ and $f(n-1)$:

\begin{aligned}
f(n) - f(n - 1) &= (2^n - k) - (2^{n-1} - k) \\
&= 2^n - k - 2^{n-1} - k \\
&= 2^n - 2^{n-1} \\
&= 2^n - 2^{n-1} \\
&= 2(2^{n-1} - 2^{n-2}) \\
&= 2(f(n-1) - f(n-2))
\end{aligned}

showing that $f(n)$ satisfies the recursive sequence and that $a_n = f(n)$.

To determine the value of $k$, use the initial condition given in the problem (only one is necessary, so say $a_1 = f(1) = 1$) and solve for $k$:
\begin{aligned}
f(1) &= 1 \\
2^1 - k &= 1 \\
2 - k &= 1 \\
k &= 1 \\
\end{aligned}

Therefore, $a_n = f(n) = 2^n - 1$.

Comment: :I like your approach, it is interesting to me.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$

1.Characteristic equation

$b_n:=a_n+1$

$b_n-2b_{n-1}=0$

The characteristic equation is now $x-2=0$

So $b_n=2^nA \ \ \ a_n=2^nA-1$ and A is 1 from initial conditions

[How to get the characteristic equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166743/how-to-get-the-characteristic-equation&ved=2ahUKEwjK08XIjbCDAxUVS2cHHTAYC0cQFnoECEgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3IkhesrwiTye_NR636fOht)

2.Simple manipulation

Divide by $2^n$ on both sides

$$\frac{a_n}{2^n}-\frac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Now add equations for n,n-1,n-2 and so on to get

$$\frac{a_n}{2^n}-\frac{a_1}{2}=\sum{\frac{1}{2^r}}=\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^n}$$

Comment: seems interesting solution. Can you add more explanation on how to get the charactersitic equation in step (1)  and  how to get the equation in step (2) before you divide by $2^n$

Comment: step(2) simply uses the original recurrence relation

Comment: MathLibre texts has a good read on characteristic equations

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(z)=\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function.  The recurrence implies that
$$\sum_{n \ge 2} a_n z^n = \sum_{n \ge 2} (2a_{n-1}+1) z^n$$
Equivalently,
$$A(z) - a_1 z = 2z \sum_{n \ge 2} a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \sum_{n \ge 2} z^n = 2z A(z)+\frac{z^2}{1-z}$$
Solving for $A(z)$ yields
$$A(z) = \frac{a_1 z+z^2/(1-z)}{1-2z} = \frac{z}{(1-2z)(1-z)} = \frac{1}{1-2z} - \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n \ge 0}(2^n-1) z^n,$$
which immediately implies that $a_n=2^n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already given how to do it in a standard way by solving characteristic equation or using induction hypothesis... But if you believe in math for fun, you may want to follow along... :)

---

Let $f(x)=2x+1$.

Notice that:

$$a(n)=\underbrace{f\circ f \circ\ldots\circ f}_{\text{$n$ times}}(0)$$

Applying $f$ on a whole number is same as appending a $1$ to the end of its binary form.

$f^{n}(0)$ is same as appending $n$ $1$'s to end of $0$.

$$f^{n}(0) = \underbrace{{11\ldots 1}}_{\text{$n$ times}}$$

What happens if you add a $1$ to this value? You will end up with $1$ followed by $n$ zeroes $0$ which is precisely $2^n$. $$\therefore f^n(0)=2^n-1$$

---

For the sake of variety, I will also add a wild approach which is akin cracking a nut with sledge hammer. :)

Consider the linear transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (2x+y, y)$ over $\mathbb R^2$.
Its matrix is given by: $\mathscr A =\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}\tag*{}$
Clearly,
$\begin{pmatrix}f(x)\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\mathscr A\begin{pmatrix}x\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\tag*{}$
and
$\begin{pmatrix}f^n(x)\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\mathscr A^n\begin{pmatrix}x\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\tag*{}$

Since, $\mathscr A$ is upper triangular, it’s immediately clear that its eigenvalues are $2$ and $1$. Now, find the corresponding eigenvectors $(-1, 1)$ and $(1,0)$ respectively in order to diagonalize $\mathscr A$.
$\mathscr A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\tag*{}$
Now raise it to the power of $n$,
$\begin{align}\mathscr A^n &=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2^n & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\\ &= \begin{pmatrix} 2^n & 2^n-1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \end{align}\tag*{}$
Thus, $\begin{pmatrix}f^n(x)\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2^n & 2^n-1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\tag*{}$

Now just substitute $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I did not know two other answers had been posted while I was typing out this answer, so here is my answer:

The obviously easier method which is to look at the pattern (or the formula given to prove), check its validity for $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 3$ and assume it to be true for $a_n$ and prove it for $a_{n+1}$ like such:

Assuming $a_n = 2^n + 1$, multiply this by $2$ to get $2a_n = 2^{n+1} - 2$ but $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 1 \implies a_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} - 2 + 1 = 2^{n+1} - 1$

Thus if the formula is valid for $1,2$ and assuming it to be valid for $n$, we proved it to be valid for $n+1$, put $n = 2$ to get it is valid for $3$ and $n = 3$ to get it is valid for $4$ and so on (this is also called principle of mathematical induction)

Now for the better method, I only get one method in mind to prove it without assuming anything which is as follows:

\begin{align}
a_1 &= 1 \tag1\label1 \\
a_2 &= 2a_1 + 1 \tag2\label2 \\
a_3 &= 2a_2 + 1 \tag3\label3 \\
\vdots & \\
a_n &= 2a_{n-1} + 1 \tag{$n$}\label{n}
\end{align}

Multiply equation $r$ by $2^{n-r}$ and add all equations from \eqref{1} to \eqref{n} and see that equation $r$ + equation $r+1$ gives $2^{n-r-1}a_{r+1} = 2^{n-r-1} + 2^{n-r}$ and following through this "chain reaction" of equations, we get $a_n = 1 + 2 + 4 + \dots + 2^{n-1}$

$\therefore a_n = 1 + 2 + 4 + \dots + 2^{n-1} \tag{$n+1$}\label{n+1}$

multiplying this equation by $2$ to get:

$2a_n = 2 + 4 + 8 + \dots + 2^n \tag{$n+2$}\label{n+2}$

equation \eqref{n+2} - equation \eqref{n+1} gives $a_n = 2^n - 1$ (all middle terms $2, 4, 8$ cancel out).

This proves the formula $a_n = 2^n - 1$